# Mail send with printf function in mail body not working using PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

I want to send mail using PHP.

Mail body's content include printf function. But this `printf` function is not working in mail body.
I want to display remaining warranty year month and days using PHP.

My code is

```
$message.='<p>'.printf("%d Years, %d Months, %d Days\n", $years, $months, $days).'</p>';
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of Content-Type in your PHP mail header

try with this header it will work

```
$headers = '';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: from@email.com'.PHP_EOL;

mail("to@email.com", $subject, $message, $header);
```

[PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) means **"End of line"** (\n\r). Its good practise to use PHP_EOL of mail headers

Answer (score 0):

Please use sprintf() instead of printf(). Because printf() display the result on the screen

```
$message.='<p>'.sprintf("%d Years, %d Months, %d Days\n", $years, $months, $days).'</p>';
```